# 2 pipes going into the cold side of my water heater

Tags: plumbing, water, heater

Anyone know why I would have 2 pipes going into the cold side of my hot water heater?[image]!

Comment: Nope. Just one photo. I had a larger one but I had to cut it down due to size restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be for a hot water recirculation system with a dedicated return line. Cold water would come from the cold water supply, while somewhat cooled off water would return to the heater from the recirculation loop on the hot water supply, after having been pumped from the hot supply to the furthest fixture on the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar system on my water heater and the additional pipe was for a heat recovery system from my ac compressor. Mine was installed in the early 80's but with ac compressors being so much more efficient now, the heat recovery system didn't work nearly as well as it did with my old unit. I have removed many additional pipes going into water heaters as they just aren't needed anymore and people didn't want them tied into their ac units for fear of failure. I also removed my additional pipes when I replaced my water heater. You could possibly find out that your's isn't even connected anymore.